# Why would I need an HTML5 Audio library?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I notice that there are many libraries out there for playing HTML5 audio, but ain't the whole idea of HTML5 audio that we don't need a library for this to work properly?

If I don't need Flash fallback, but a simple solution for streaming music (my own) that can also play each track after each other, do I then need a library like [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) or [Soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)?

I know I need different audio formats, but that's not a problem as I won't have many tracks online.

Answer (score 1):

The "whole idea" of HTML5 audio is that end users and web page authors shouldn't need to rely on a browser *plugin* to play audio - the functionality should be included in the browser, and controllable directly from standardised HTML/JavaScript.

I haven't used an HTML5 audio library, but looking at the jPlayer and Soundmanager2 home pages, it looks like the main functionality they offer is fallbacks for browsers that don't support HTML5 audio.

I suspect they might also have some built-in custom UI for playing audio though, in case you don't like the native audio controls that browsers provide.

Answer (score 1):

You could use straight-up HTML5, but you'd soon realize that has a whole host of problems.

Library's like jPlayer (which is great by the way) account for many common issues like browser support, optimization and fall-backs etc.

If you want to code all that yourself you can, but a popular library will be leaps ahead and it's the wise choice to take.

The truth is, HTML5 offers very powerful features, but its support is thin at this current moment in time. It's all to make your life easier!

Comment: "browser support" and "fall-backs" sound like the same thing. Is there a distinction? What optimizations do the libraries offer?

Comment: They do sound similar, but what I meant was that, in addition to the library 'detecting' a support for the feature or not, it also supplies a 'fallback'. They're not the same though. Take for example that each browser may 'support' HTML5 audio, but have slightly different ways of doing it. A good library will allow you to code it once, for all situations, without needing to worry about the browsers specific implementation of the HTML5 specification.

Comment: With regards to "a whole host of problems", [here's an article detailing some](http://phoboslab.org/log/2011/03/the-state-of-html5-audio) from a couple of years back.

Comment: Gotcha. Are there appreciable differences between browser implementations of HTML5 audio though? (Specifically playing audio via the `<audio>` tag, which is what I understand to be the scope of the question, rather than the APIs for generating audio.)

Answer (score 0):

HTML-5 audio actually encompasses two distinct factions at this point. One is the audio tag and the other is the Web Audio API. The former is a quick mechanism for playing an embedding audio files, the latter is a way to play,process and manipulate audio in a low-latency manner acceptable for game development and more professional environments where features like reverb effects,filters,"3D" sound and other characteristics are needed. But to answer your question, the only real reason to use a library for the HTML 5 audio tag is (in my opinion) for backward compatibility between browsers as well as ease of use for things like multi-shot file triggering and event handling.

Comment: Thanks that was a good explanation. I might need additional things like event handling, so will dig into the jplayer.